# Looping through a namedtuple

Tags: python, csv, namedtuple

I am a Python noob but not new to programming. I have searched StackOverflow extensively and didn't find the answer (or didn't understand what I have found).

This is what I want to do

1. Take info from a CVS file (50 fields) an put into memory
2. Loop through info from another source
3. In each iteration, loop through the CSV info, find what I need and do something with it together with the info from the other source.

I want to know how to write the CSV info into memory and how to loop through it inside another loop

Thanks.

This is how far I got

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import csv
from urllib import parse
from collections import namedtuple

# set up namedtuple structure
    ARecord = namedtuple('ArchiveRecord', ['id', 'post_author', 'post_date']) #plus 50 fields

# load csv info to memory 
with open("site-export.csv",encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
    r = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='|', quotechar='"')
    for arch in map(ARecord._make, r):
        print(arch.id) #print to show that something is happening

# loop that gets info from other source
    # loop through csv info from memory 
        # get field values per row by name
        # do something together with info from both source
```

Comment: Do you want to put all your instances of `ARecord` into a list?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the question. I want to put all the CSV info to something in memory that can be looped through. I have read that namedtuple is the best way to do it.

Comment: @HananCohen You may consider `csv.DictReader`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open("site-export.csv",encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
    r = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='|', quotechar='"')
    csvInfo = [ARecord._make(row) for row in r]

# loop that gets info from other source
    for arch in csvInfo:
        # use information in arch
```

Comment: Thank you @abukaj this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `csv.DictReader` and with `fieldnames` method you can put the column names into a list.

If those names are the same as the field names in your `namedtuple`, then you can easily access them.

`namedtuple` can return its data represented as a dict, using `_asdict()` and then you can access the values by the column names returned by the `DictReader`.